# APPサーバーからDBサーバーにmysqlログインができない

Tags: mysql, centos

ConoHaサーバー(CentOS 7.2)を使用しています。
APPサーバーからsshログインし、外部DBサーバーにmysqlログインしようとすると下記のエラーが出ます。

```
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user ’neko'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

APPサーバーからDBサーバー間のpingではちゃんと返ってきています。
DBサーバー側ではMySQLの権限をAPPサーバーのIPアドレス、ユーザー名、パスワードを設定しました。

APPサーバー側からのログインは下記のコマンドで行いました。

```
mysql -h localhost -u neko -p
```

ちなみに上記の「localhost」はこのような書き方でいいのでしょうか？
phpMyAdminを開くと、サーバーの欄にlocalhostと記載があったので、そのまま書いたのですが、IPアドレスを記入するべきでしょうか？どちらにしてもログインはできなかったのですが。。

ずっとここがログインできなくて非常に困っています。
あとどこか見直すべき点などありましたらぜひご教授お願いいたします。

---追記です。
MySQLは5.7になります。

Comment: ありがとうございます。
リンクも参考にさせていただき、ログインの時にDBサーバーのローカルIPアドレスを指定して、ポート番号3306を解放、そしてユーザー権限をワイルドカードで作成したらうまく接続できました。
ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Appサーバからの接続にはlocalhost指定はできません。
まずはDBサーバにて、ip指定で接続できることを確認し、その後APサーバからの接続にはトライされてみてはいかがでしょうか。
外部からの接続の設定方法は下記のリンクが詳しいです。
http://linuxserver.jp/%E3%82%B5%E3%83%BC%E3%83%90%E6%A7%8B%E7%AF%89/db/mysql/%E5%A4%96%E9%83%A8%E6%8E%A5%E7%B6%9A%E8%A8%B1%E5%8F%AF%E8%A8%AD%E5%AE%9A